# Small perturbations and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

1. Suppose $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix. Given $\epsilon>0$, can one find a rank one matrix $B$ with euclidean norm at most $\epsilon$ such that $A+B$ has $n$ distinct complex eigenvalues?
2. Given a non-zero vector $x$, can we find $B$ as above with the *additional* property that $x$ is an eigenvector for $A+B$?

Edit: From the answer below, I realize it is too much to ask. What about:

3. Suppose $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix. Given $\epsilon>0$, can one find a rank one matrix $B$ with euclidean norm at most $\epsilon$ such that $A+B$ is diagonalizable?

Comment: What about matrix $A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No for question 1: for example, if $A=0$, then $A+B$ will still have $n-1$ zero eigenvalues.

No for question 2, in general, even if the answer to 1 was "yes": note that eigenvalues vary continuously with the entries of the matrix, and so, for almost all values of the entries, the eigenvectors will vary continuously.

Added:

No for question 3: for example, if $A$ has all entries zero except a few above the main diagonal, a rank one matrix will no be able to kill all the nontrival part of the Jordan canonical form, in general.

Comment: Ok, I realize that I am asking too much. I will make an edit .

Comment: Added an answer to your 3rd question.